# stopping the server side execution with custom validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I have a form with a custom validator for minimum age.  I have a submit button on that form. When the custom validator kicks in, I don't want the code inside the submit button to execute so when the minimum age requirement is not met and I set the ServerValidateEventArgs args to false. Code inside the submit button gets executed

Below is my custom validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator Display="None" ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" OnServerValidate="ageValidator" ControlToValidate="txtDOB" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"  />
```

below is my date of birth text box:

```
<input   id="txtDOB" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="text" data-role="datebox" value="" runat="server"  ></input>
```

I also have submit button on that page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" data-icon="check" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="true"   />
```

below is my custom validator code:

```
protected void ageValidator(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Parse(txtDOB.Value.ToString());
    TimeSpan sp = DateTime.Now - dtStart;

    if (sp.Days < 16 * 365)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "You have to be at least 16 ";
        return ;
    }
    else
        args.IsValid = true;
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // some code here
}
```

when I click on the submit button, the custom validator code gets executed and then whether the args is true or false, the code in submit button gets executed. I don't want the code in submit button to be executed if args is false, but this is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `btnSubmit_Click` you can test for `Page.IsValid` (which your custom validator setting to **false**) and decide whether or not to do anything else based on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Comments** :

You can set the error message in the ASPX itself by property ErrorMessage = "You have to be at least 16 ". No need to `return`  in the method.

You have to add `Page.IsValid` in the method like this.

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    SomeLabelMessage.Text = "Page is valid.";
}
else
{
    SomeLabelMessage.Text = "Page is not valid!";
}
```